# Django Queryset get lowest/highest price! one to many

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have some Django models, a Product class and a Price class. A product can have multiple prices, but only the "newest" one the current price! I have a product query where I need the lowest price and the highest price, but only the current prices. If a product have 2 and more prices it's only the newest price I want!

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

An example in a queryset where I want the lowest and highest, but only the current prices. The same thing for "price__price__gt". This should also only be the current prices I want it to work with.

```
Product.objects.filter(price__price__gt=1000).order_by("price")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can get the Product w/the minimum price.

Make a 'current_price' property on the product model,

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    @property
    def current_price(self):
        """Returns last price if any prices exist, else None
        """
        if self.price.all():
            return self.price.order_by('-created')[0].price
```

for the current_price property to work correctly, you need to add the 'price' related name in your Price model product fk field,

```
class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name='price')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now you can filter for the minimum price as follows,

```
qs = [p for p in Product.objects.all() if p.current_price]
# Returns a list of products that have a current price

# To get the lowest price,
cheapest_product = min(qs, key=lambda x: x.current_price)
cheapest_product.current_price

# To get the highest price,
most_expensive_product = max(qs, key=lambda x: x.current_price)
most_expensive_product.current_price
```

You can make a model manager to do this for you, see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for more info.

Preferably you want a manager that can work like this,

```
Product.objects.cheapest()  # returns the single cheapest 'current' price.
Product.objects.most_expensive()  #returns most expensive (highest) price
```

Comment: Thanks ... But I really want a way without making an extra field on the Product model, but if that is the only way then I have to do that.!

Comment: There are no extra fields created by this solution. The @property method doesn't create a database field. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: If you're referring to the @property/'current_price', this is just a python function to help you work with your model, the database is not touched..

Comment: Arhhh ... sorry, now i get you .. perfect, I will just try it out .. I think that this is just what I need .. Nice one .. thanks!

Comment: I have made you mods, but way can't I do something like this ... Product.objects.filter(current_price__gt=1000)

Comment: you won't be able to use model properties in a filter like that bkz the filter method generates sql to run on the db. Since in the db there is no column called 'current_price', the sql queries won't work. You'll have to use python to work w/'current_price' and other properties.

Comment: alternatively you can add code to the models save method and add an extra field (which will make a db column) for current price, then you can use the filter method.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
from django.db.models import Max

prods_with_prices = []
for prod in Product.objects.all():
    prices = Prices.objects.filter(product = prod).annotate(current_price=Max('created'))
    prods_with_prices.append({'product': prod, 'price': prices.current_price})
costly_prod = max(prods_with_prices, key = lambda x: x['price'])['product']
cheap_prod = min(prods_with_prices, key = lambda x: x.['price'])['product']

print "Most expensive product: " + costly_prod
print "Least expensive product: " + cheap_prod
```

Comment: @pkdkk Just edited, as my first answer had a bug. Let me know if this works for you.